# Docker-compose postgres error: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have an error with postgres in docker-compose. When I start docker-compose with `docker-compose up -d`, everything is right. But after 1-2 days, the error occurs. And I noticed, that when it occurs the linux machine become really slow, and I can't do any operations with docker. I tried: `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` to restart docker daemon, but it just stops and do nothing. But when I reboot machine, the lags disappear. I consider that something wrong with config(`docker-compose.yml`).

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes: 
  common-volume: 
  postgres:

services:
  nginx: 
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports: 
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.1.5
  postgres:
    container_name: docker-postgres
    ports: 
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT:-5432}:${POSTGRES_PORT:-5432}
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    image: postgres
    networks:
      app_net: 
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.8
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  common:
    container_name: docker-common
    build: ./common
    volumes: 
      - common-volume:/usr/src/common
  auth_service:
    container_name: docker-auth-service
    build: ./auth-service
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - REDIS_HOST=10.5.0.7
    env_file: 
      - .env
    volumes: 
      - common-volume:/usr/src/common
    expose: 
      - "8080"
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
  redis: 
    container_name: redis
    image: 'redis:4-alpine'
    expose: 
      - "6379"
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.7
networks:
  app_net:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Comment: Did you find any solution man ? I have landed into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had confronted similar issue. The problem is with this line of code for both *postgresql* and *auth_service* configuration:

```
restart: always
```

replace it with:

```
restart: no
```

or comment it out!